# Setting custom notification sound (and vibration) via setSound() does not work

Tags: java, android, audio, notifications, vibration

When trying to create a notification within my app, setting a custom notification sound does not work, the system default sound is used. Also, I am trying to enable vibration on my notification, which doesn't work either.

I am trying to set the sound as follows (relevant snippets, see full code below):

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bell);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
        "Order notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    channel.setSound(sound, 
        new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
            .build()
    );
    channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 500});
} else {
    notificationBuilder
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 500})
            .setSound(sound);
}

notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

My custom sound is a one second long sound snippet, sampled at 44.1 kHz, stored as `res/raw/bell.wav`. I also tried converting the snippet to different other formats, I tried `mp3` and `ogg` without success.
Regarding the vibration: `android.permission.VIBRATE` is included in the manifest.

I don't have any more ideas what I am doing wrong. Here is the full code of the `sendNotification()` function which creates and posts the notification.

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bell);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_web)
                    .setContentTitle("New order")
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Order notifications",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build();

        channel.setSound(sound, att);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 500});
    } else {
        notificationBuilder
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 500})
                .setSound(sound);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After you create a NotificationChannel you cannot change things like lights, sound and vibrate. Maybe this is the issue. To see changes you need to first remove the app and install it again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately, even after uninstalling the app and even changing the channel name, this did not fix my issue